# Grouping data based on repetitive records using R

Tags: r, split, grouping, multiple-records

I have a dataset which contains repetitive records/common records. It looks something like this:

```
| Vendor | Buyer | Amount |
|--------|:-----:|-------:|
| A      |   P   |    100 |
| B      |   P   |    150 |
| C      |   Q   |    300 |
| A      | P     | 290    |
```

I need to group similar records together but I do not want to summarize my amount. I want to have the amount value being represented individually. The output should like something like this:

```
| Vendor | Buyer | Amount |
|--------|:-----:|-------:|
| A      |   P   |    100 |
| A      |   P   |    290 |
|        |       |        |
| B      | P     | 150    |
|        |       |        |
| C      | Q     | 300    |
```

I thought of using split(), but since my original data has too many records, the split function creates too many lists and it becomes tedious to create new datasets from them. How can I achieve the above stated output with any other method?

EDIT:
Let us assume that we have an additional column called date and the dataset now looks like this:

```
| Vendor | Buyer | Amount | Date      |
|--------|:-----:|-------:|-----------|
| A      |   P   |    100 | 3/6/2019  |
| B      |   P   |    150 | 7/6/2018  |
| C      |   Q   |    300 | 4/21/2018 |
| A      | P     | 290    | 6/5/2018  |
```

Once, each buyer and vendor is grouped together, I need to arrange the dates in ascending order for each buyer and vendor such that it looks something like the below one:

```
| Vendor | Buyer | Amount | Date      |
|--------|:-----:|-------:|-----------|
| A      |   P   |    290 | 6/5/2018  |
| A      |   P   |    100 | 3/6/2019  |
|        |       |        |           |
| B      | P     | 150    | 7/6/2018  |
|        |       |        |           |
| C      | Q     | 300    | 4/21/2018 |
```

and then remove the single transactions to get the final table containing only

```
| Vendor | Buyer | Amount | Date     |
|--------|:-----:|-------:|----------|
| A      |   P   |    290 | 6/5/2018 |
| A      | P     | 100    | 3/6/2019 |
```

Comment: Looks like you need `order` or `arrange` `library(dplyr); df1 %>% arrange(Vendor, Buyer)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, I did it using arrange, but could you please help me with the edit part of my question?

Answer (score 0):

In the following we sort the data frame and add a group column which allows easy subsequent processing of individual groups.  For example, to process the groups without creating a large split of `DF`:

```
for(g in unique(DFout$group)) {
  DFsub <- subset(DFout, group == g)
  ... process DFsub ...
}
```

**1) Base R** Sort the data and then assign the group column using `cumsum` on the non-duplicated elements.

```
library(data.table)

o <- with(DF, order(Vendor, Buyer))
DFo <- DF[o, ]
DFout <- transform(DFo, group = cumsum(!duplicated(data.frame(Vendor, Buyer))))
DFout
```

giving:

```
  Vendor Buyer Amount group
1      A     P    100     1
4      A     P    290     1
2      B     P    150     2
3      C     Q    300     3
```

I am not sure this is such a good idea to do in the first place but if you really want to add a row of NAs after each group:

```
ix <- unname(unlist(tapply(DFout$group, DFout$group, function(x) c(x, NA))))
ix[!is.na(ix)] <- seq_len(nrow(DFout))
DFout[ix, ]
```

**2) data.table**  Convert to data.table, set the key (which sorts it) and use `rleid` to assign the group number.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, Vendor, Buyer)
DT[, group := rleid(Vendor, Buyer)]
```

**3) sqldf** Another approach is to use SQL.  This requires the development version of [RSQLite on github](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite).  Here `dense_rank` acts similarly to `rleid` above.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *, dense_rank() over (order by Vendor, Buyer) as [group]
  from DF
  order by Vendor, Buyer")
```

giving:

```
  Vendor Buyer Amount group
1      A     P    100     1
2      A     P    290     1
3      B     P    150     2
4      C     Q    300     3
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Vendor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Buyer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("P", "Q"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(100L, 
150L, 300L, 290L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: The first way helped me around with the answer. In the present scenario, if I would want to eliminate all the buyers along with vendors who have single transaction, in this case Vendor=c and Buyer=Q. Also, let us assume that we have a date field as well in the problem set. So, once we group together buyers and vendors, how shall we sort them in ascending order?

Comment: `subset(DFout, ave(group, group, FUN = length) > 1)` will remove groups having one row.  The answer already shows how to do sorting.

Comment: I tried the first method in my original data and it doesn't seem to work. For each buyer there will be multiple vendors. So, I first want to group similar buyers together, then group similar vendors for each buyers and then sort the transaction in ascending order for each group separately.

Comment: If you want to change the question in that way then sort by Buyer and Vendor instead of by Vendor and Buyer.